# Pool of threads bound to event streams, to push asynchronous events in order

Tags: java, concurrency

I manage a set of client-supplied event sinks, each subscribed to its own event stream. Each sink will typically push data into its own network pipe, which means there is exploitable concurrency in pushing events into sinks. At the same time I need to ensure proper event ordering. This is a naive approach:

---

```
final Set<Sink> sinks = new HashSet<>();
final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

---

```
eventSource.addListener(new SourceListener() { 
  public void sourceEvent(final Event event) {
    final Sink sink = resolveSink(sinks, event);
    pool.submit(new Runnable() { public void run() { sink.accept(event); }});
}});
```

---

This will not guarantee proper ordering. If my thread pool associated each event queue with a single thread and dispatched my accept-event tasks to that particular thread's task queue, this would be robust. I am looking for a basic idea or a sketch of a workable approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean each `Sink` should handle events in the same order as they occur, then this is exactly an application of [Actor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) . Numerous Actor frameworks implemented in Java exist, the simpliest is [df4j](https://github.com/rfqu/df4j/tree/master/df4j-core) developed by me.

---

### Addendum

*(by Marko Topolnik, a summary of the discussion in the comments)*

Maintain a queue per each event stream and use an executor service. When a new event appears, submit a task that drains the queue into the sink. The task must not be submitted unconditionally, but only if such a task is not already running. To ensure that, use a boolean flag (one per each event stream) that is set when submitting the task and reset by the task when done.

Comment: I am familiar with the Actor model, but the devil is in the detail. How does your solution work with respect to my use case? How many threads, is the thread pool flexible, how do you ensure both concurrency and proper ordering?

Comment: df4j uses any Executor supplied by user, or fixed threadpool (num of available processors) by default. All actors run concurrently, all messages for a given actor are queued and then handled sequentially in the order of arrival. A concrete Actor should impelment method `void act(M message)`.

Comment: Can you please point me to the right place in your code where the sequential handling of messages is done? I've looked around, but the class hierarchy is quite deep and I'm not sure what I'm looking at.

Comment: `com.github.rfqu.df4j.core.Actor` declares `StreamInput<M> input` which contain `LinkedQueue<T> queue`. The `BaseActor` is general dataflow actor with multiple inputs of different types, while `Actor` is a processing node with single input queue.

Comment: I think I'm getting it now. Each Actor maintains its message queue and  a drain-queue task is submitted to the executor service in each situation where there may be new messages on the queue. I'm currenly working on something similar in my code. Your code doesn't prevent two drain-queue tasks at the same time, I think. One task may be running while the other will be blocking until the former realeases the lock.

Comment: Be careful not to submit actor task which is already submitted. My code does not allow simultameous drain-queue tasks, and of course there is no lock hold when messages are handled, execpt short-living locks to put and get messages from the queue.

Comment: How do you ensure that? I'll have a flag somewhere that is cleared by the submitted task upon its completion.

Comment: `boolean fired` in `BaseActor`

Comment: I think this is it, then, our solutions are aligned. If you find time and inclination, edit the outline of this solution into your answer to make it eligible for acceptance. In either case, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure independence I would have a single threaded pool for each client.

You can wrap the client listener to trigger the same event on the client's thread pool so it can be treated as a simple listener by the rest of your code.

Comment: How many clients do you have, or is it one listener per client? Can you partition the clients, like ConcurrentHashMap partitions keys, for a total of say 10 - 40 groups?

Comment: There may be more than a thousand clients, one listener per client. Grouping clients is a heuristic, there could be issues with load balancing in that case. I currently really like your idea + stopping the thread in a period of inactivity.

Comment: No, using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with `corePoolSize=0` and `maxPoolSize=1` makes no sense since tasks want te be enqueued in preference to starting threads beyond `corePoolSize`. Therefore tasks will never run. In practice this is detected and I get a `RejectedExecutionException`. Back to square one.